# Overflow hidden issue with double scrolling on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, overflow, hidden

The problem is that I have a body (which it can't be positioned fixed because it causing bugs to the current project) with a lot of content and a modal with scrollable content inside, the problem is that on iOS if I turn the overflow to hidden nothing happens.

In my case, setting `height: 100vh` and `overflow: hidden` to `class="parent"` is not working.

I tried different things and tried different hacks to solve this issue but nothing fixed yet I saw here also different methods but for different situations.

I looked also for overflow hidden alternatives but nothing found yet...

If you guys have some ideas/refs/a way to solve it post it here I appreciate, thank you.

Here is the snippet https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJQoJR

```
<body class="modal-open">
    <div class="parent">
        <p>Body scrollable content</p>
        <div class="container-child">
            <div class="child">
                <p>Modal scrollable content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why is your container-child `position: fixed` and not `position: absolute` ?

Comment: @Sam because It needs to be the only thing that you can see (to be sticky).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got pretty good results by adding this to your css:

```
body.modal-open > .parent {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And to make the modal 'bouncy' on your iOS device, change your `.container-child` css to:

```
.container-child {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* <-- added */
}
```

Here's a demo on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzJXPJ

Comment: I will mark this as the most useful solution until it will be fixed in WebKit. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. Disabling the bouncy effect can only be done using position: fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Putting the overflow hidden on your html tag might help:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: This could help 99% of the devs that have the same issue, the problem is that in my case it brings the content from parent to the top (something like scrollTop = 0 and same as position: fixed; top: 0 to the body) and that's not ok.